# localizing historical allusions (Waterloo; Honnoji)

Tags: idioms

English occasionally uses "Waterloo" idiomatically to refer to a situation where someone meets their (ultimate) defeat. (historical allusion to Napoleon's defeat at the Battle of Waterloo)

> "That playboy fell hard for Susan. He finally met his Waterloo"
>
> "This is your Waterloo. Soon, you'll be Napoleon Blown-apart." (Sideshow Bob)

My question: would a nativized version work in Japanese? I've toyed with the idea of using Honnoji, in reference to Oda Nobunaga's defeat.

> (1) ?「裁判で勝ちつつあってから、田中対鈴木事件は先生の本能寺だった」
>
> ("After a string of victories in court, the lawyer met his Waterloo in the case of Tanaka v. Suzuki.")
>
> (2) ?「俺は世界一の魔導師！この決闘はお前の本能寺だ！」
>
> ("I am the world's best wizard! This duel will be your Waterloo!")

Comment: 「年貢の納め時だ」みたいなもの？

Comment: 勝ちつつある means that you haven't won yet.

Comment: ここで会ったが百年目（文字数埋

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 本能寺 like that. In addition, 本能寺 is associated with *surprise attack* rather than *ultimate defeat* to me. Even if you used an explicit analogy marker (eg 彼にとって本能寺のようなものだ, まるで本能寺みたいなことになった), people are unlikely to understand what you want to mean. And 魔導師 usually refers to Western-style wizards, who don't usually know 本能寺 in the first place :)

A similar word in Japanese is perhaps [天王山【てんのうざん】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154246/meaning/m0u/), which sometimes refers to "decisive stage/battle" without using ～のような.

> ここが天王山だ。 This is the make-or-break stage.

I'm not aware of any place name which can mean *ultimate defeat* on its own in ordinary conversations.